# R - Plot: How to format in 10-base scientific notation and put it text, mtex, title etc functions?

Tags: r

I have numeric variable, say K=3.5e-5 (its values is calculated throughout my script). I want to write this value somewhere (title, as text in the plot, etc)  in my plot as:

`K_{root} = 3.5 10^{-5} cm /d`

I have tried the functions `bquote`, `substitute` and no one worked.

Let's put the question in examples. I have tried the following:

1)

```
png("exp_1.png")
kroot = 3.5e-5
plot(1:10,1:10,
text(4,9,bquote(italic(K[root])~"="~.(kroot)~"cm/d")))
dev.off()
```

Comment: Maybe [this](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Scientific-notation-in-plots-tp791499p791501.html) might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try my favorite function, paste().

```
plot(1:10,1:10,
text(4,9,gsub("e",paste("K[root]=",format(k,scientific=TRUE),"cm/d",sep=" "),replacement=" 10^")))
```

You can replace the "e" here using the function gsub. I've edited my answer to include this.

The output:

```
 > k=.0000035
 > k
 [1] 3.5e-06


> gsub("e",paste("K[root]=",format(k,scientific=TRUE),"} cm/d",sep=" "),replacement=" 10^{ ")
[1] "K[root]= 3.5 10^{ -06 } cm/d"
```

You can remove the extra spaces around  `{ -06 }` by using the function substr, if it's important, or simply leave out the curly brackets in the gsub statement.

Comment: `scientific=TRUE` will format the number with the E notation (i. e. 3.5e-05). Here I think the OP wants it with the 10 notation (3.5 x 10^-5).

Comment: Edited the answer in response.

Answer (score 1):

I try to avoid using paste inside expressions. There is generally a cleaner way to approach this:

```
expon <- floor(log10(kroot))  # returns -5
mantis <- kroot*10^(-1*expon ) # returns 3.5
plot(1:10,1:10,
text(4,9,substitute( italic(K[root]) == mantis %.% pten* expon ~cm/d, 
                        list(expon=expon, mantis=mantis, pten=" 10^")))
```

[image]